# compojure routes : How to call a function with dependencies from a route?

Tags: dependency-injection, routes, clojure, compojure

The idea is to call a certain function when a route matches. That function has dependencies . I'm new to clojure and compojure and this approach could be wrong.
But still, this is what I try to achieve.

```
(defroutes my-routes (GET "/user/list"
                      []
                   (list-users)) ; where list-users is for example (partial list-users user-service)
```

Since I didn't find a way to do this with `defroutes`, I tried to setup the routes "dynamically".

```
 (defn define-routes [services]
  (routes
    (GET "/user/:id"
         [id]
      ((:show-user services) id))
    (GET "/user/list"
         []
      ((:list-users services))))
```

When I start jetty with the routes defined like this,

```
 (defn app [services]
     (j/run-jetty (define-routes services) {:port 3000 :join? false}))
```

every call leads to an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Response map is nil
```

Is there a way to use defroutes and call functions where dependecies are injected or is ok to do it the way I tried, but I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you return the data that doesn't implement `compojure.response/Renderable` protocol, compojure doesn't know how to render it, so it expects that your result would be the whole response map.

More details can be found [in the compojure documentation](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Routes-In-Detail#returning-a-response)

So what you have to do is either implement `Renderable` for your data, or create the `ring` response yourself (presumably with some libraries), like they do in [ring.util.response](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/util/response.clj)

Comment: thanks for you answer.
The NPE I saw, was caused by the browser requesting the fav icon. The fact that I didn't see any results was caused by fact that my service expected the id as an integer and not a String.
But you answer helped me taking another go on the approach and it is working as expected now.